# How do I make selection based on JComboBox choice

Tags: java

How do I make my code activate based on JComboBox selection. I am converting metric to imperial and I need to know when to call upon methods based on when a certain option is chosen.

```
    public JComboBox<String> metricUnits = new JComboBox<String>();

    public JComboBox<String> imperialUnits = new JComboBox<String>();

    imperialUnits.setBounds(140, 65, 100, 20);
    imperialUnits.addItem("Inches");
    imperialUnits.addItem("Feet");
    imperialUnits.addItem("Yards");
    imperialUnits.addItem("Miles");

    metricUnits.setBounds(140, 20, 100, 20);
    metricUnits.addItem("Millimeters");
    metricUnits.addItem("Centimeters");
    metricUnits.addItem("Meter");
    metricUnits.addItem("Kilometer");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, you can use a lambda expression

```
JComboBox comboBox  = new JComboBox() ;
comboBox.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
 // here what do you want to do when change
    });
```